# SDL2 only returns first registered UserEvent

Tags: events, sdl-2

I register three events via `SDL_RegisterEvents`. However, `SDL_PollEvent()` only returns events of the first type and swallows the others.

This is my code (it's Go, but I don't think that's relevant here):

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    if err := sdl.Init(sdl.INIT_VIDEO | sdl.INIT_EVENTS); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer sdl.Quit()

    evt1 := sdl.RegisterEvents(3)
    evt2 := evt1 + 1
    evt3 := evt1 + 2

    sdl.PushEvent(&sdl.UserEvent{Type: evt1})
    sdl.PushEvent(&sdl.UserEvent{Type: evt2})
    sdl.PushEvent(&sdl.UserEvent{Type: evt3})
    sdl.PushEvent(&sdl.UserEvent{Type: evt1})

    event := sdl.WaitEvent()
    for ; event != nil; event = sdl.PollEvent() {
        userEvent, ok := event.(*sdl.UserEvent)
        if ok {
            switch (userEvent.Type) {
            case evt1:
                log.Println("got evt1")
            case evt2:
                log.Println("got evt2")
            case evt3:
                log.Println("got evt3")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
2019/08/04 20:10:26 got evt1
2019/08/04 20:10:26 got evt1
```

So both `evt1` events that I pushed got polled, but `evt2` and `evt3` I pushed in between vanished. I tried calling `sdl.RegisterEvents(1)` three times instead for registering the events, but the result is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only is because of go binding, specifically the line https://github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/blob/24851c1f2d98dcac2a68223a24e6f799fc921f1e/sdl/events.go#L1035 (type conversion only triggered on `SDL_USEREVENT`, which matches only with first registered event; anything else is reported as "CommonEvent", losing all extra data you may have passed) . You probably should report a bug to developer of said binding.